# Selecting particular columns in a table

Tags: sql, hibernate, select, dropwizard

I am trying to retrive only a few columns of interest with a sql query in a dropwizard hibernate transaction set up in the following way

```
@Transactional
    public List<MyObject> getInteresting() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        List<Service> services = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            String sql = "SELECT col1, col4, col7 FROM MyObject WHERE col3 = "someValue";
            SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
            query.addEntity(MyObject.class);
            services = query.list();
            tx.commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            if (tx != null) tx.rollback();

        }
         finally {
             session.close();
         }
        return services;
    }
```

Execution of this query results in a colum2, col3, col5 etc not found error. Basically it erors for the columns I am excluding from the query

Comment: did you realized the error in "MyObjectWHERE", it should be "MyObject  WHERE"

Comment: your errors are of syntaxis?

Comment: this line ***String sql = "SELECT col1, col4, col7 FROM MyObjectWHERE col3 = "someValue";*** should be like: ***String sql = "SELECT col1, col4, col7 FROM MyObject WHERE col3 = \"someValue\"";*** Don't know if that is your problem...

Comment: I edited the question, the error is that it is expecting all columns in the query

Comment: can you paste the error in the question?